# BATCH: set a systemvariable with a path form another txt file

Tags: batch-file

I would like set a systemvariable in batch with a path which is written in a txt file. I already have the syntax but I don't know how can I read one line in the txt file and use the read line as variable path.
Can anyone help please?

```
setx -m thul type C:\Temp\pfade.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\temp\pfade.txt") do setx -m thul "%%a"
```

Or

```
set /p "value="<"c:\temp\pfade.txt"
setx -m thul "%value%"
```